# show() div problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, show, html

I am an absolute beginner in this field. I have written the following code but it's not working. Can someone explain where is the error?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").show("slow");
    });
</script>

<button>show</button>
<div style="min-height:300px; min-width:400px; border:10px solid grey; display:none;"></div>
<a href="http://#" style="display: none">this is a link</a>
```

Comment: It's always helpful to say what exactly is happening. Is it a javascript error? What's the error? ctrl+shift+j on firefox to check.

Comment: Maybe it is working, but as your div is empty you might not notice it.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? We don't know what you expected to happen, and we can't deduce from the code _because the code is "not working"_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You execute the jQuery before the button is there. So at the point jQuery is executed, the button is not existent.

The solution is to use `$(document).ready(...)`.

All elements on a page (HTML) are parsed to the DOM of that page. The DOM is a hierarchical collection of all elements. You can select elements out of it using jQuery.

However, obviously the DOM needs to be fully there before you can select the elements. In your case, you first select the button, and create it *afterwards*. That does not work. At the time of the selector the button does not exist yet.

Using jQuery's [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), you can defer the function containing selectors until the DOM is fully loaded and parsed - at which time the selector works because the elements are there.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("button").click(function(){
            $("div").show("slow");
        });

});
        </script>

        <button>show</button>
        <div style= "min-height:300px; min-width:400px; border:10px solid grey; display:none;"></div>
         <a href="http://#" style="display: none">this is a link</a>
```

Comment: thank you very much. problem solved...can you tell me bit how ready function work..will be very  kind of you..

Answer (score 0):

You code runs before the button is created so it cannot bind the event.

So you need to put your code in the `document.ready` event. In jQuery this is handled by `$(document).ready(handler)` or `$(handler)`.

Documentation at http://api.jquery.com/ready/

---

Fix to your code to make it work

```
$(function(){ 
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").show("slow");
    });
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/vkrzt/

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to listen for the click event before the button exists.  Try waiting for the page contents to load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("div").show("slow");
        });
    });
</script>

<button>show</button>
<div style= "min-height:300px; min-width:400px; border:10px solid grey; display:none;"></div>
<a href="http://#" style="display: none">this is a link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/bQUFE/ your code works (the div is shown when you click)

If you don't have this result always check:

1)that you loaded jquery before your script

2)Always use $(document).ready() like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").show("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the javascript is executed before the document has loaded, so the click-handler can't be attached to the button. to avoid this, wrap your code into a domready-function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").show("slow");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably is working but as your `<div></div>` is empty you might notice it.

Also make sure you only run your JQuery script AFTER the div has been added to your HTML.

May I also suggest to use better identifiers, because you might eventually have many div's and buttons on your page.

Example:

```
<button id="btn1">Click me</button>    
<div id="hidden_div" style="display: none">
    Hello there!
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('button#btn1').click(function() {
        $('div#hidden_div').show('slow');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: You'd need to remove the sapce there though.

Comment: @pimvdb Sorry, you're right. Typo'd as I was trying to be too fast. :-)

Answer (score -1):

you need to give your elements "id"

so:

```
<button id="mybutton"></button>
```

and

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Then you'll use $("#mybutton") or $("#mydiv") to call these

Comment: this isn't the poblem here. anant is leaving out the domready-function, so there is no `button` when the javascript gets executet - and so the click-handler can't be attached.